# adding path_prefix in root_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, localization, routes, rails-i18n

I have added localization in my website and it is working fine, except two points

1. When I open website for example www.test.help.com it shows this url instead it should also show locale as I am using path_prefix in my application controller.
2. When I click to change the language,the url is not changing instantly

here is my code snippet

application.rb

```
    include HttpAcceptLanguage::AutoLocale
    before_action :set_locale

   def default_url_options(options = {})
{ :path_prefix => I18n.locale }

 end

def set_locale
if cookies[:educator_locale] && I18n.available_locales.include?(cookies[:educator_locale].to_sym)
  l = cookies[:educator_locale].to_sym
else
  if params[:path_prefix].present?
    l = params[:path_present]
    cookies.permanent[:educator_locale] = l
  else
    if (http_accept_language.preferred_language_from(http_accept_language.user_preferred_languages).include? "en")
       l = 'en'
       cookies.permanent[:educator_locale] = l
    end
    if ( http_accept_language.preferred_language_from(http_accept_language.user_preferred_languages).include? "fr")
      l = 'fr'
      cookies.permanent[:educator_locale] = l
    end
  end
  cookies.permanent[:educator_locale] = l
end
I18n.locale = l
end
```

My setting controller

```
 def change_locale
l = params[:locale].to_s.strip.to_sym
# puts "---------"                                                                                                                                                                                             
# puts l                                                                                                                                                                                                       
l = I18n.default_locale unless I18n.available_locales.include?(l)
cookies.permanent[:educator_locale] = l
url_hash = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path URI(request.referer).path    url_hash[:locale] =l                                                                                                                                                                                         
redirect_to url_hash
```

end

Then my routes

```
 get '/change_locale/:locale', to: 'settings#change_locale', as: :change_locale
 get "home/index"
   root 'home#index'
```

Once I click on any link, then path prefix is visible but not directly on opening the website.

Comment: In set_locale function you don't have a any default else any in case of `if` are all invalide.

Comment: but I have only tested on  english and french browser and these condition should work atleast for these cases

Comment: Okay but is the translations working on the homepage (route_path) according to the locale ?

Comment: yes when I click on Home or any other link, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you arrive on any url for the first on the application (root_url, users_url ...) the url is displayed in your web browser before you entrer in set_locale.
Then if you visit an other link in the application the locale will be added in the url. But the translations will works anyway with the locale you setted in `I18n.locale`.

Comment: Can you precise this one ?
'When I click to change the language,the url is not changing instantly'

Comment: when I click on changing the language from en to fr, url should instantly change from en to fr also,  but it stays en even though text changes

Comment: In `change_locale ` you don't set `I18n.locale` with the new selected locale.

Comment: thanks, it worked, but how or where should I handle root_url for first time to have locale in url

Comment: Is it really a big deal to not have the locale in the url for the first time ?
You can use some javascript if you really want to have the locale in the url the first time you visit the web  site.